# replace a word or number in a sentence that is less than 8 using awk or sed

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have an example below where I need to replace the column 9 value if it is less than 8 else exit or ignore using sed or awk function:

```
) in datadbs extent size 16 next size 4 lock mode row;
```

If I use the below awk function it only prints the value I need in column 9, but I still want to maintain the sentence structure.

```
echo ") in datadbs extent size 16 next size 4 lock mode row;" | 
 awk '{if ($9 < 8 ) print 8;}'
```

OUTPUT:

```
8
```

What I want is the below:

```
) in datadbs extent size 16 next size 8 lock mode row;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without knowing any `awk` I'd suggest to change the parameter and print everything:

```
echo ") in datadbs extent size 16 next size 4 lock mode row;" | 
  awk '{if ($9 < 8 ) $9 = 8; print;}'
```

Comment: Or even just `awk '$9 < 8 { $9 = 8 } 1'`

Answer (score 3):

```
sed -e 's/\S\+/&\n/9; s/ [0-7]\n/ 8/'
```

Answer (score 2):

***sed*** alternative:

```
s=") in datadbs extent size 16 next size 4 lock mode row;"
echo $s | sed 's/size [0-7] lock/size 8 lock/'
```

Comment: As long as no-one writes the number there with leading zeroes

Comment: *with leading zeroes* - in that case the number can be treated as octal and that's not the case